# Conversion to number, number is not recognised

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

having a problem with conversion

select '53475,12'::number(15,5) as tt, l_extendedprice from lineitem;

Error message:Numeric value '53475,12' is not recognized

Comment: When you deal with numbers you have to take in consideration the international settings of separatos, for example. Could you please specify better your question, and format it better ?

Comment: It's not supported "yet", but there is a popular demand for it. So I expect it to be developed. You need to go with the workaround mentioned by Marcel.

Answer (score 1):

Default separator is "." and not ",". That's why it's crashing - it's looking for the ".", not finding it and thus not recognizing the numeric value.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal.html

You could run REPLACE() to replace all "," by "." and then apply the cast.

Answer (score 0):

`select '53475.12'::number(15,5) as tt;`

gives:

| TT |
| --- |
| 53475.12000 |

but

`select '53475,12'::number(15,5) as tt;`

gives the same error:

> Numeric value '53475,12' is not recognized

I am sure there is a option that control parsing of numbers.. But the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#fixed-position-numeric-formats)'s say otherwise